# iOS Timer loop that executes a certain action every X minutes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, timer, nstimer

I am trying to execute a certain block of code every x amount of time, but it seems that all I am doing is executing it during that time. Here's a block of my code.

```
while (TRUE) {
    NSTimer *countDown = [NSTimer
                       scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(x)
                       target:self
                       selector:@selector(timerHandle)
                       userInfo:nil
                       repeats:YES];

}
```

Any ideas as to how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written, this is an infinite loop, creating an `NSTimer` every loop iteration.

Try it without the `while` loop.  This should cause `[self timerHandle]` to be invoked on interval `x` by a single background thread/timer.  The Apple guide to NSTimer usage (including as others point out, how to properly *stop* your timed task) is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000807-CJBJCBDE).

Comment: Yes.  You'll also need a way to stop the timer.

Comment: Thanks, I think this did it. I'll be checking the guide for the stopping part.

Answer (score 5):

Try this: (It will call `executeMethod` on every 5 sec)

```
if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(executeMethod)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
    });
}
else{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(executeMethod)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
}
```

Write the code you want to be executed in `executeMethod` method. Hope this helps.. :)